# Difference between "No" and "Not"

Tags: grammar

I am unable to clarify the difference between No and Not,

As per my knowledge I have read that "Not" is used with helping verb always but in the following question "Not" is used with main verb (Be). Is is right or wrong If right then plz define.

He is a good teacher

He is not a good teacher

Comment: This effectively duplicates a closed question on this forum: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64369/what-is-the-difference-between-no-and-not It was closed because the answer is readily found at other sites, e.g., http://www.myenglishteacher.eu/question/what-is-the-difference-between-no-and-not-an-how-to-use-them/

Comment: I don't think I have enough information to provide a complete answer, but I think a good way to view it is that "not" is used to *negate* something (so, "negative" = "not positive", "boy" = "not girl", "wrong" = "not right", although some would insist on recognizing the neutral options of each example here).  So something either "is" or "is not"

Comment: **"To be or not to be, that is the [OP's] question"**

Answer (score 2):

**No** and **Not** are "not" interchangeable in the same way "**Yes**" and "**Is**" aren't.

Your examples;

"*He is a good teacher*" doesn't sound right when we say "**He yes a good teacher**", likewise "*He is not a good teacher*" is correct while "**He is no a good teacher**" is just wrong.

**No** is a great response where as **Not** describes the state of something. For example, "JAVA is **not** a real programming language". Did you ever learn JAVA? **No**, I did **not**.

Comment: On the other hand, *he is no teacher* is grammatically correct, though it doesn't have quite the same meaning as *he is not a teacher*.

Answer (score 0):

*No* is a determiner, it must precede a noun, and it will take the place of an article in things that can attach to a noun.

> I took the ball from Suzy.
>
> I took no ball from Suzy.

Exception is where *no* can be used to answer questions like *yes*.

> No, I don't want to go.
>
> I told him no.  I'm not going.

*Not* is an adverb.

It can precede infinitives and gerunds.

> I wanted him not running through my lawn.
>
> Not to be difficult, but I think we should leave.
>
> She was only concerned about him not going to the store.

But not present participles:

> Go into the not running van and start it for me. (Wrong, has to be *Go into the van that is not running ...*)

Otherwise, an auxillary verb is required when using *not* and if one is not otherwise present, *do* is used:

> I had gone to the park.
>
> I had not gone to the park. (Auxillary there so just add "not.")
>
> I had 2 pieces of candy.
>
> I did not have 2 pieces of candy. (*Had* in the previous sentence is not an auxillary verb, so one is needed.)
>
> The books were not stacked properly.
>
> Someone not stacked the books properly. (Wrong.  Sounds like a 2-year old learning to speak or a caveman.)
>
> Someone did not stack the books properly. (Ok.)